# Selenium / Java : How to write element locator for an element with aria-selected=false

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, karate

We are unable to locate and click at an element with "aria-selected" = "false" on an HTML page.
We have tried different way to write xpath locator and css selector but none of them worked.
While inspecting a bit more on page, we found that this element has a "aria-selected="false" in it
and when we click on it and it shows results then this value changes to "aria-selected="true"

[image]

We have tried with below xpath:

```
(".//*/span[@class='tab-button-text'][contains(text(),'Orders')]")
```

Note: Even though it does not matter which framework, we are using to use this element. However i would like to mention that, we have been trying it for two separate framework such as

1. Karate framework
   and other one,
2. Selenium, Cucumber BDD with java

Comment: Why is JavaScript tagged?

Comment: my karate feature file is 
'''  Given driver 'https://test.com' '''
>    * delay(5000)
>  * waitFor(".//*/span[@class='tab-button-text'][contains(text(),'Orders')]")
> When click(".//*/span[@class='tab-button-text'][contains(text(),'Orders')]")
    * delay(6000)

Comment: CSS selector `'*[aria-label="sidebar"]'`

Comment: Hi @nlta  , i am getting error with css selector as well
 'loginOMS.feature:6 - evaluation (js) failed: click('*[aria-label="sidebar"]'), java.lang.RuntimeException: js eval failed twice:document.querySelector("*[aria-label="sidebar"]").click(), error: {"type":"object","subtype":"error","className":"SyntaxError","description":"SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list","objectId":"-137200642617226304.1.7"}
stack trace: com.intuit.karate.driver.DevToolsDriver.eval(DevToolsDriver.java:300)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [ariaSelected](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/ariaSelected)

The ***ariaSelected*** property of the Element interface reflects the value of the **`aria-selected`** attribute, which indicates the current "selected" state of elements that have a selected state.

Value: A DOMString with one of the following values:

- *true*: The item is selected.
- *false*: The item is not selected.

Selected/unselected state of this [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) attribute doesn't effects your tests.

---

To locate the element you can you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *xpath*:

  ```
  ("//span[@class='tab-button-text' and contains(text(),'Orders')]")
  ```
- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  ("div.tabbar.show-tabbar > a.tab-button.has-title.has-icon span.tab-button-text")
  ```

Comment: It works with "and" in xpath. Thanks for help